# How can I know if browser is Chrome vs Firefox from web extension popup JavaScript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using the `chrome` namespace for both Chrome and Firefox, but would like to know which browser is running the web extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check `chrome.app` which is absent in Firefox:

  ```
  const isFirefox = !chrome.app;
  ```
- Check for `browser` which is absent in Chrome:

  ```
  const isFirefox = window.browser && browser.runtime;
  ```

  (the additional check is to avoid false positives on pages that have an element with `id="browser"` that creates a named property on `window` object for this element)
- Use the asynchronous [browser.runtime.getBrowserInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getBrowserInfo).

P.S. `navigator.userAgent` may be changed during debugging in devtools when switching to device mode or via `about:config` option in Firefox so it's an unreliable source.

Answer (score 6):

Links to extension resources have different schemes in Chrome and Firefox.

```js
const isFirefox = chrome.runtime.getURL('').startsWith('moz-extension://');
const isChrome = chrome.runtime.getURL('').startsWith('chrome-extension://');
```